# GridBagLayout row weights

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I fill a GridBagLayout JPanel with dynamic content that I read from a database. My question is if I can find a way to set the last rowWeights to 1.0 . Usualy when I create static GridBagLayout panels I can do something like this:

```
    GridBagLayout gbl_accPanel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_accPanel.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0};
    gbl_accPanel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    accPanel.setLayout(gbl_accPanel);
```

But now, in my case, I dont know how many rows I will have so I need a way to push all the content at the top, this means to make the last row weight 1.0 to fill the rest of my container.

Obviously I can keep a count of the elements I add, than set the rowWeights, than revalidate(); repaint(); but I dont like this way of approach. So is there any better way ?

Here is a picture if my question is unclear:
[image]

what I'm doing now:

```
public void setAccountRowWeights(int n)
{
    weights = new double[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n-1; ++i)
        weights[i] = 0.0;
    weights[n-1] = 1.0;
    gbl_accPanel.rowWeights = weights;
}
```

Comment: I can add weighty = 1.0 to the last component and its fine but still, I have to determine the last component myself. I was thinking if I can set the gridbaglayout so that my last component will always fill the rest of the container automaticly.

Comment: For me the question is still unclear. Do you want all components to occupy same space along the `X-Axis` for a given record ? If yes, then you simply can divide the number of components like `1.0/(double)noOfComponents`, to get the `weightx` value for each component. If not, then you can try `GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER` for the last component. Though if you can provide a small drawing of what exactly is needed, that might be of more help in understanding the situation :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need any other special features of the `GridBagLayout`, you could use a `BorderLayout` instead, where the "north" part is an embedded `GridLayout` with an unspecified number of rows (i.e. the "rows" argument is 0).

```
public class LayoutTest implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LayoutTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel north = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 25));
            p.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            north.add(p);
        }
        f.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.setBackground(Color.RED);
        f.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks prep. I might adapt this approach if I can do all my stuff with BorderLayout. :)